# why have high AUC and low accuracy in a balanced dataset for SVM

Tags: svm, roc, auc

I used LIBSVM to classify 256 classes. My dataset is about 5000-10000. For SVM, I used one against one strategy to train my models. Now, I get the results of low accuracy (15%~30%) but high AUC (>90%). I suppose that one cannot obtain high AUC (0.9 and higher) if Acc of the corresponding predictive model is low (13-30 %)?
I refer to the Open Source Python Library (scikit-learn )to compute the AUC of many kinds of problems. (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-py)
This is used these code  to compute AUC：

```
# compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
fpr     = dict()
tpr     = dict()
roc_auc = dict()

# test_label_kernel: the true label of one insance
# LensOfLabel      : the number of all classes
y       = label_binarize( test_label_kernel, classes = list(range(0,LensOfLabel,1)) )
#sort_pval: the prediction probability of SVM
for i in range(LensOfLabel):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = metrics.roc_curve( y[:,i], sort_pval[:,i] )
    roc_auc[i]        = metrics.auc( fpr[i], tpr[i] ) 

# First aggregate all false positive rates
n_classes = LensOfLabel
all_fpr = np.unique(np.concatenate([fpr[i] for i in range(n_classes)]))

# Then interpolate all ROC curves at this points
mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(all_fpr)
for i in range(n_classes):
    mean_tpr += interp(all_fpr, fpr[i], tpr[i])

# Finally average it and compute AUC
mean_tpr /= n_classes

fpr["macro"] = all_fpr
tpr["macro"] = mean_tpr
roc_auc["macro"] = metrics.auc(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"])
print( ("macroAUC: %.4f") %roc_auc["macro"] )

#compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = metrics.roc_curve( y.ravel(), sort_pval.ravel() )
roc_auc["micro"]              = metrics.auc( fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"] )
print( ("microAUC: %.4f") %roc_auc["micro"] )
```

The ROC curve is；

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEUqr.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucbE6.png

Comment: I suppose that one cannot obtain high AUC (0.9 and higher) if Acc of the corresponding predictive model is low (13-30 %)

Comment: Are  10000 instances not too few for 256 classes?

Comment: Where do you calculate the AUC? And what threshold do you use?

Comment: The threshold is calculated by the function of metrics.roc_curve, is about <0.2